# Power BI - Programmatically sign in

Tags: authentication

I'm trying to write a web app which embeds some Power BI reports. The data is on-premises so I cannot use the new solution available (Power BI Embedded). Now the inconvenience of using the old approach (https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-integrate-a-power-bi-tile-or-report/) is that the consumer of the web page needs to be a Power BI user which needs to sign in in order for the web app to finally get an authentication token (there is a couple of page redirections that need to happen before).
So my question is, is there a way to do the Power BI Sign In in a programmatic way? so in that way I can just use one Power BI account for getting the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also experimenting there,
this thread helped me with just that (see post #8):

http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/How-to-use-Power-BI-Rest-API-without-GUI-authentication-redirect/m-p/14218#

Basically:

**POST request to:**
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token

**Body, form-url-encoded:**

- grant_type: "password"
- scope: "openid"
- resource: "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api"
- client_id: your client id
- client_secret: your client secret
- username: that username
- password: that usernames password

Then you directly get the token.

Also it might be good to consider security concerns like described here: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/ under "When NOT to Use This Feature"

Comment: If this is new to people (which is was for me) you can download an application called Postman and test this out by entering the above into the 'Body' tab of the POST request.

Comment: @Sheheen nice, I use Paw for mac btw.

Comment: Where to get that client id and client secret?

Comment: That depends, I would suggest to google for something like "azure get client id client secret <your kind of app>" where <your kind of app> could be "function app" or so ...

Answer (score 0):

It's just a coincidence that I am doing the same. Actually Power BI provides a Rest API to do this very easily. You need to register an app at Azure portal which will provide you with a client id and client secret. Now you can use the rest API and these details.

```
POST: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token
```

and in the body, you need to send these details and in the header, you need to set 
`Content type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
data: {
    grant_type: password
    scope: openid
    resource: https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api
    client_id: {Client ID}
    username: {PBI Account Username}
    password: {PBI Account Username}
    client_secret: {Enter client secret here}
}
```